# extract value from an bad xml string

Tags: regex, xml

First of all i would like to big thanks to everyone in this forum. 
I was trying to extract one xml tag value in the below given xml string.

Input String was :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<nonpublicExecutionReportAcknowledgement xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping /../xmls/SDR/recordkeeping/fpml-main-5-5.xsd">
    <header>
        <inReplyTo messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id">sit:GDS:1644644:1442512894123:SRD0IFR119094084</inReplyTo>
        <sentBy>DTCCEU</sentBy>
        <sendTo>RRasdfjasdfasdkllkd4</sendTo>
        <creationTimestamp>2015-10-14T16:47:30Z</creationTimestamp>
    </header>
    <originalMessage>
        <nonpublicExecutionReport fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <header>                
                <messageId messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id">sit:GDS:1644644:1442512894123:SRD0IFR119094084</messageId>
                <sentBy messageAddressScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/cftc/interim-compliant-identifier">RRasdfjasdfasdkllkd4</sentBy>
                <sendTo>DTCCEU</sendTo>
                <creationTimestamp>2015-10-14T05:54:38Z</creationTimestamp>
            </header>
        </nonpublicExecutionReport>
    </originalMessage>
</nonpublicExecutionReportAcknowledgement>
```

Regex i was used to extract messageId was "(?<=>).*?.(?=\</messageId)" which is working fine. But when it comes as single xml string it was not working as expected.

Failing for the below input string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><nonpublicExecutionReportAcknowledgement xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping /../xmls/SDR/recordkeeping/fpml-main-5-5.xsd"><header><inReplyTo messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id">sit:GDS:1644644:1442512894123:SRD0IFR119094084</inReplyTo><sentBy>DTCCEU</sentBy><sendTo>RRasdfjasdfasdkllkd4</sendTo>   <creationTimestamp>2015-10-14T16:47:30Z</creationTimestamp></header><originalMessage><nonpublicExecutionReport fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><header>                <messageId messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id">sit:GDS:1644644:1442512894123:SRD0IFR119094084</messageId><sentBy messageAddressScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/cftc/interim-compliant-identifier">RRasdfjasdfasdkllkd4</sentBy><sendTo>DTCCEU</sendTo><creationTimestamp>2015-10-14T05:54:38Z</creationTimestamp></header></nonpublicExecutionReport>   </originalMessage></nonpublicExecutionReportAcknowledgement>
```

Output required was :- "sit:GDS:1644644:1442512894123:SRD0IFR119094084"

```
the value should get extracted between 
<messageId messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id"> and </messageId>
```

Could you please help me to build the regex string for the above problem it will be a great help.

Cheers,
KS

Comment: Your string does not appear to be an incorrect XML. So why not using `XML` librairies to parse it (Linq or another one) or an XPath expression?

Comment: Hi zwoRmi,    i can't parse the xml because, it required code fix. if i get a regex to extract the value that will be a great help. Otherwise we need to fix the code, it will impact our current prod..

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<inReplyTo messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id">([a-zA-Z0-9:]+)</inReplyTo>
```

Comment: its works fine but it should not match <inReplyTo messageIdScheme="www.abc.com/msg_id"> and </inReplyTo> . I need only between the value

Comment: You have round brackets for grouping. Regexp finds the expression with tags and group highlights the value. Please check http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.